# Exception while parsing negative double numbers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm coding a peace of code that extracts some data from a DB. And the problem is that I want to convert a negative number string "−2.8" to a double. Pretty easy, I thought. I tried first with:

```
var climateString = "−2.8";
var number = double.Parse(climateString);
```

With this result:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

So I thought again, searched on google, and got new answer:

```
var climateString = "−2.8";
var styles = NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign |NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
var rit = double.Parse(climateString, styles);
```

Epic fail again:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I thought again, I cannot be so stupid as not to know how to do such a simple task. I tried this:

```
 var climateString = "−2.8";
 var doue = Convert.ToDouble(climateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Yes, the exact same exception again. I started looking a the number, and, I realized on the negative sign. Look this number carefully  "−2.8" this is not a negative number this. This is a negative number "-2.8". Look at those signs again "----- −−−−−" not the same. Parsing a string with a different sign character throws an exception : S. So, anyone has an idea, how to parse it elegantly to a double number in C#? Thak you!

Comment: You know the problem is that you have an incorrect character in it. So remove it?

Comment: Or perhaps, clean up the source data in the database first.  Garbage in, Garbage out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute a hyphen for the dash:

```
var climateString = "−2.8".Replace ("−", "-");
var number = double.Parse(climateString);
```

(You might want to be on the lookout for other strange characters coming out of that database, though.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers, I will try this approach. I thought there where any NumberStyle to handle this.

Comment: Right you are! I added a second answer with the proper way to do it.

Comment: A better approach.

Answer (score 21):

Proper way to do it:

```
var climateString = "−2.8"; 

var fmt = new NumberFormatInfo();
fmt.NegativeSign = "−";
var number = double.Parse(climateString, fmt);
```

Comment: Will a regular negative sign still work after adding this format?

Comment: Don't know offhand. I'd think not, though.

Comment: If it doesn't work this answer is practically wrong even if technically correct.

Comment: Just tested it. Doesn't work. Which makes this answer wrong for any practical purposes.

Comment: This did not work for me and I took the code listed verbatim. I

Answer (score 7):

Might be an old post but for anyone else reading this...

You have NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign, that should probably be NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign otherwise it will not accept a - sign anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use TryParse instead of Parse method because it gently handle you error if any.

Code -

`var test1 = "-123.95";
decimal result;
decimal.TryParse(test1, out result);`

you'll get parsed double value in *result*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
decimal.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal numberOut)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).