# How i can convert Negative Float with point in String to Negative Float with Point in C#?

Tags: c#, string, exception, runtime-error, formatexception

I have a String with Negative Float with Point,and it looks like this:

`-1.0`

And i need to convert it to float,so it need to be a:

`-1.0f`

I tried this:

```
bool isNegative = false; //float in my string isnt a negative
string mystr = "-1.0"; //my string
float myfloat = 0.0f; //my float

if(mystr.Contains("-")) 
{ 
    isNegative = true; 
    mystr.Replace("-"); 
} //if my string is negative,set a bool to true,and remove - from string

if(isNegative==true) 
{ 
    myfloat = float.Parse(mystr) * -1.0 
} //if bool is true(is says number in string is negative),parse string to float and make it negative
else 
{ 
    myfloat = float.Parse(mystr) 
} //if bool is false(number in string isnt negative),just parse a number
```

That code is working i think,but it throws a `System.FormatException`,so i think i got that exeception,because code cant parse a string with point(`.`).I got a exception at `float.Parse` method.

If you want,i will show a full code,where i got error,upper code is just concept of my real code,there is real code:

```
bool redNeg = false; //red number isnt negative
bool greenNeg = false; //blue number isnt negative
bool blueNeg = false; //green number isnt negative
string[] args = GetArgs.ExtractArguments(LineText); //get strings from "translate(0.0,0.0,-1.0);"
string red = args[0]; //string1,default is 0.0
string green = args[1]; //string2,default is 0.0
string blue = args[2]; //string3,default is -1.0
if (red.Contains("-")) 
{ 
    redNeg = true; 
    red.Replace("-", ""); 
} //if string1 is negative,set negative bool to true and remove - from string

if (green.Contains("-")) 
{ 
    greenNeg = true; 
    green.Replace("-", ""); 
} //if string2 is negative,set negative bool to true and remove - from string

if (blue.Contains("-")) 
{ 
    blueNeg = true; 
    blue.Replace("-", ""); 
} //if string3 is negative,set negative bool to true and remove - from string

float redd = 0.0f; //default float of string1
float greenn = 0.0f; //default float of string2
float bluee = 0.0f; //default float of string3

if (redNeg==true) 
{ 
    redd = float.Parse(red) * -1.0f; 
} //if negative bool of string1 is true,set float to negative
else 
{ 
    redd = float.Parse(red); 
} //if its not,parse it

if (greenNeg == true) 
{ 
    greenn = float.Parse(red) * -1.0f; 
} //if negative bool of string2 is true,set float to negative
else 
{ 
    greenn = float.Parse(green); 
} //if its not,parse it

if (blueNeg == true) 
{ 
    bluee = float.Parse(red) * -1.0f; 
} //if negative bool of string3 is true,set float to negative
else 
{ 
    bluee = float.Parse(blue); 
} //if its not,parse it

gl.Translate((float)redd, (float)greenn,(float) bluee); //render function,dont touch it
```

After some comments,i edited my code to this one:

```
        var fmt = new NumberFormatInfo();
        fmt.NegativeSign = "−";
        //LineText is "translate(0.0,0.0,-1.0);
        string[] args = GetArgs.ExtractArguments(LineText); //get strings from "translate(0.0,0.0,-1.0);"
        string red = args[0]; //string1,default is 0.0
        string green = args[1]; //string2,default is 0.0
        string blue = args[2]; //string3,default is -1.0
        float redd = float.Parse(red,fmt); //default float of string1
        float greenn = float.Parse(green, fmt); //default float of string2
        float bluee = float.Parse(blue, fmt); //default float of string3
        gl.Translate((float)redd, (float)greenn,(float) bluee); //render function,dont touch it
```

But i still have FormatException,but now i got it on

`float bluee = float.Parse(blue, fmt); //default float of string3`

Which is an string with negative number.

Comment: Why do you need the `f`?  Thats only needed when defining a float variable, when you parse the string its implied.  Also, your formatting is _horrible_

Comment: see that gl.translate method,so that method is accepting only float type,with `f`.

Comment: Exactly *which* `float.Parse` call is throwing said exception? Which of the lines you pasted?

Comment: `else { redd = float.Parse(red);` is throws error

Comment: And have you tried printing this string before parsing, to see what it holds?

Comment: redd is 0.0 in string

Comment: i printed it using `MessageBox.Show(redd);`

Comment: Its very unclear what your problem is. `float.Parse("-1.0")` will work and do exactly what you would expect it to (ie parse the string and output a float with a value of -1). If you are having problems with float.Parse then you need to show us exactly what input you are passing to the parse method that is causing the problem and then we might be able to help you diagnose the problem. If you don't know what the value you are passing to float.Parse is then you really need to look into how to use a debugger to find this information.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647548/exception-while-parsing-negative-double-numbers-in-c-sharp

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: `float.Parse("     -1.0    ")` will parse correctly so white space shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Byte We need the _exact_ value of `red`.  My earlier comment remains true, the `f` is 100% not needed in your context.  Plus `float.Parse()` will handle a negative sign with no issue.  You need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: The parse without culture parameter is dependent on the regional settings of your machine

Comment: @maccettura I sayed i need a `f`,because method gl.Translate only accept float with `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force the culture info to use a dot for decimals.
Because your machine's regional settings could be using a comma for decimals.

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
            System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo ni = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)ci.NumberFormat.Clone();
            ni.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

            string s = "-1.0";
            var result = float.Parse(s, ni);
```

Comment: O MY GOD,ITS FINNALY WORKS,THANK YOU VERY MUCH,RENO

Comment: @Reno: Could you explain what the actual problem was and why this answer fixed it? Your answer would be much better with an explanation!

Comment: Added some comments.