# FormatException when parsing a negative number

Tags: c#, console, formatexception

So I have this code:

```
String inputValues = Console.ReadLine();
string[] values = inputValues.Split(" ");
int firstValue = Int32.Parse(values[0]);
int secondValue = Int32.Parse(values[1]);
int thirdValue = Int32.Parse(values[2]);
```

Somehow, I get an formatexception thrown on the firstvalue-value, saying that the string is in an incorrect form when I put a negative number like -2 in there. I also get some weird brackets in the console where I put my values in. You can see them in my picture. What are those and are they doing something to my values because for sure you can parse negative numbers right?

[image]

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. I sugest you log what the values are that you are trying to parse (or use the debugger and step through).

Comment: What is the exact value of `values` after user input? Please double check what your last `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` is - are there any brackets?

Comment: Check this. Duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647548/exception-while-parsing-negative-double-numbers-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please share your code too... Without looking at your code its not possible to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: Given that [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ziEARw) works fine, I'm guessing it's either something to do with the value you're entering, or there's additional code not included in your question that's causing it (also note I had to change `" "` to `' '` to get it to compile)

Comment: Have you tried trimming the values before parsing? Since you are using bash, it may well be you have a superfluent `<LF>` or something alike.

Comment: Here is the complete code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LJFum

Comment: @Fildor No, I have not tried to trim them.

Comment: I should add that it works fine with positive numbers.

Comment: So a friend of mine tried the code and it worked for him. Can this be related to me using OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        String inputValues = Console.ReadLine();

        var formatSign = new NumberFormatInfo();
        formatSign.NegativeSign = "−";

        string[] values = inputValues.Split(" ");
        int firstValue = Int32.Parse(values[0],formatSign);
        int secondValue = Int32.Parse(values[1],formatSign);
        int thirdValue = Int32.Parse(values[2],formatSign);
```